# Java webapp add version to app static content for caching

Tags: java, caching, servlets, struts2, servlet-filters

For static content such as images, css, js, i would like to set a really long cache time(max-age or expires) for the browser to cache and also want to provide version or hash in the path so updated content will be loaded.

The tech stack is Java 8, struts 2, tomcat. 
What is the easiest way to add the version or MD5 hash to the url path for static content?

Currently what i have is css1.css or js1.js .. What i want is something like {v}/css1.css so when the new version is deployed browser is forced to get the update.

We do have lot of JSP pages, and i don't want to update the urls to add the suffix version no. in each of them. Looking for something where the URL's can be auto converted something in Filter without editing all the static files.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: which package manager are you using? We solved the same problem with our legacy application by adding npm in our gradle build and then using node file revving tools.

Comment: We are using maven for building and releasing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24484085/573032

Comment: @MaverickRiz conceptually maven and gradle work the same (mostly). You can research how to run npm tasks through maven and then use a tool like node-file-rev to do the file-revving.

Comment: Will try that. Thanks

Comment: @MaverickRiz please dont forget to update or accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used maven front-end plugin which runs npm tasks. Integrated webpack into the project to bundle the js and css.